# Angular Load Component Dynamicaly by Url

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular project. I created a popup that has several tabs

[image]
Each tab has an address and when it is clicked, it should be displayed in the body of the pop-up
These tabs are added dynamically
Each tab should be loaded only once
The method I used to implement it was that I add a ng-template for each tab and load the component with the **componentFactory** and inject it into the ng-template and display the ng-template when the tab is active.

```js
export class TabLoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    public mapService: ComponentMapService
  ) {}
  @ViewChild(TabLoaderDirective, { static: true })
  appTabLoader: TabLoaderDirective;
  @Input() componentName: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
    console.log("tabLoader Is Active");
  }
  loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory =
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        this.mapService.getCompoent(this.componentName).component
      );
    const viewContainerRef = this.appTabLoader.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

But the problem is that I did this with the component name, not the router address
I want to know if there is a better way to implement it?

Comment: so do you want to do it with the router URL, is that your question? Do you want to share the state so that you can navigate to any number of tabs from the URL itself? your approach is so far good., Share the router config and template if that's what u are looking for!

Comment: I did not use the router method and I find and load the component through the name of the components, but I want to find a way to do it with the address. The way that comes to my mind is to create a  router outlet for each tab and load the address in it, but I don't know how.

Comment: do all the tabs displays the same template/view or it differs? if the view of the tab differs for each tab, then your above approach is enough. can you add a minimalistic example in stackblitz about what you try to achieve and where you exactly blocked?

Comment: Doesn't the `<router-outlet>` make this possible already? The only thing still to do is set the modal state based on the `ActivatedRoute` name...